# how to make a checkbox editable when clicked in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-checkbox

im trying to make a to do list in android studio with checkboxes, the idea is to be able to add checkboxes to a linear layout every time i press a button. this is pretty simple but i want to be able to change the checkbox text when i click on it after ive created it.

i tried to make the text box with no text and just place a plain text beside it   but i havent found a way to place both of them on the same line of the linear layout. the plain text just appears on the line underneath. i would like to know if theres any way to make a custom component that would make the checkbox text editable when clicked on the text and check the box when clicked on the check box itself that i could place it in the linear layout.

this is the code ive done to add another checkbox to the linear layout:

```
    public void click(View v)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        cb.setText(t.getText());
        this.ll.addView(cb);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Checkbox what is it: [Checkbox source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CheckBox.java)

Now you know you have a "CompoundButton" , which is a Button if you look at the
[source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java)

which is a TextView if you check the source [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java)

The EditText, which is used for editing texts it is a TextView if you check the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java)

So the parent it is a TextView and in your custom component you must combine the EditText added functions and values to your CheckBox. If you have time and you aren't lazy you can do it for sure, just extend the CheckBox and add the event and handling.

Solution ofered by BAHMAN is fast and simple ( but not enough elegant for me), if you want a quick result you can do that solution or based on that one:

Declare a View named "container" in .xml layout. At your code ( runtime ) first add the Checkbox. On the Click event remove the Checkbox ( if you arenn't added at .xml, but in code you can do it ) and add an Edit text, where you listen the finishing editting event. Then you remove the Edit text and put back the Checkbox. In this case you have not doubled the components and listeners.

Since it is a TODO list, can have many Checkboxes, I would choose the last solution offered by me. If you do an expensive, commercial product, than the first solution offered by me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a check box to your layout you can add a horizontal linear layout or a custom view extending `LinearLayout` containing a `CheckBox` and an `EditText` at first set visibility of `CheckBox` to gone when user enters some text in `EditText` and presses Enter set `CheckBox` label equal to text of `EditText` then set visibility of `EditText` to gone and set Visibility of `CheckBox` to Visible. Again when a check box is clicked do similar job.

It is better for you to create a custom View (a class extending `LinearLayout`) and do above job in that class. and every time you need a new check box you can add this custom view to your layout instead of adding check box to your layout.